Locally Compact Lie Groups and Matrix Lie Groups
Let $G$ be any Lie group with a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}(n, \mathbb{R})$; but assume that I only deal with a locally compact, connected (topologically) component around its $e \in G$ element, say $K \leqslant G$. Suppose further that this “nice”, local Lie subgroup admits a finite dimensional representation. Under these assumptions, can I say that my beautiful local subgroup $\cong H \subset \text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ by Ado’s theorem?
Secondly, suppose that I have a principal bundle $E=M \times G$ for manifold $M$. If your answer to the previous question is: “Yes”, then can I say that I may have a product space $U \times H$ locally for $E$, where $U \subset M$? If not, what are impediments that prevent from having such a local trivialization of $E$?

Every Lie group is locally compact (at least, with the textbook definition of  a Lie group). And every local Lie group admits a faithful finite-dimensional representation.

@MoisheKohan, so I can say that there is a matrix Lie group isomorphic to this local Lie subgroup $K$?

Locally isomorphic rather than isomorphic.

@MoisheKohan, Yes correct “locally isomorphic” :) I see! Then, this is exactly what I need for my purpose. To be able to locally define a principle bundle :) Thanks for the confirmation!
